# automate SIEM respons with webhooks

Tags: elasticsearch, webhooks, elk

I have a SIEM and a firewall and I wanna automate reponse in my SIEM. for exemple when the SIEM detect a port scanner, it will creats automatically a new rule in my firewall to block that IP.
and to be able to do that, I read that I have to use a **webhook**

Could you please give me more informations about webhooks as I didn't understand it: how to make one, how to connect it to the firewall and SIEM ..... etc

Thanks for your help